# How is code quality maintained in linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have heard about tools like sonarsource which help in maintaining the code quality and test coverage. Why is not linux kernel development use such tools to make the work easier ?. It would be great to see the facts about the code like what sonarsource offers rt ?. Moreover it would give a overall management type of look into the linux kernel development which would be great.

Comment: The quality attribute readability is not maintained.

Comment: I'm pretty sure quality control for the Linux Kernel is "if your code sucks, it ain't getting into mainline".

Comment: In addition to other tools, there is a script called checkpatch.pl which will report coding style issues.  It is under linux/scripts in the kernel tree.

Comment: Everything is great as of now but there is a some sort of manual work involved right ?. If there is a tool like sonar used it could give everyone some very good statistics and overall view of the kernel like how its getting improved and what are the current issues...Why is not such a tool used ?. Im not a supported on sonar or embrace it but just feel using things like that could make the development a lot more easier to maintain. Making the steps easier means a lot on involvement at a younger level i guess